# Grails bottom-up development

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm considering Grails for my next project, but I will be given a complete database before I start writing the application around it. I have read that Grails is a domain-centric environment, supporting *top-down* development, so that does not fit my development mode.

Hence my question: is it possible to write a Grails app around an *existing* DB structure? What would be the best approach? Can Grails be used without a full ORM, but with a pattern like ActiveRecord? Or are there tools to generate Grails classes from an existing DB schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> are there tools to generate Grails classes from an existing DB schema?

[Grails Reverse Engineering Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/db-reverse-engineer)

Comment: http://grails.org/plugin/db-reverse-engineer is an officially supported plugin and works a lot better than GRAG.

Comment: indeed, works better, thanks! (btw, if you post your comment as an answer, i will accept it)

Answer (score 1):

Yes Grails can be used without an ORM.

We have written non-GORM domain classes that fetch their data from RESTful APIs without ever going to a permanent storage. So Grails is in no way forcing you to use GORM.

Depending on your legacy DB schema you can either just add params to your GORM classes to fit that schema or you can just write your own data accessors for your database.

Giving further tips / ideas without further information regarding your project and database schema is impossible, so I'll leave it at that :)

Comment: How do you fetch you data from the REST APIs? Do you have some sort of GORM for REST or do you have a service for that?

Comment: AFAIK there is no GORM for REST, but you can use HTTPBuilder and  XMLSlurper/JSONSlurper to easily access the service and read the data returned

Comment: We write our own classes to src/groovy which are given access to our own httpService to GET, POST, etc data to different APIs and fetch data from there. And just to make it more performant we wrap those queries in an EhCache with short TTL values so that not *every* single request to the site needs to refresh the data from the API.